# Is the differential equation $y'''x''+x^2 y'' +x'y'=0$ linear?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Would an equation like this be considered an ordinary linear differential equation (linear in respect to $y$)?

$$\frac{d^3y}{dt^3}\dot{}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\dot{}x^2+\frac{dy}{dt} \dot{}\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$$

Comment: Is this a single equation for two different functions $x$ and $y$? Then it's nonlinear since you have their derivatives multipled, not to mention $x^2$. Assuming $x$ is known it is linear in $y$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean't linear in $y$. Is the equation linear in respect to $y$? $x$ is not known - it's a variable.

Comment: Equation is either linear $in$ $all$ $unknowns$, or not linear. You can say it is linear in $y$ but if $x$ is also an unknown it's not of much use.

Comment: @Conifold I see. Why would multiplying two derivatives make the equation non-linear? I mean if the equation contained the term $xy$ it would be linear so why would having the term $dy/dt \dot{} dx/dt$ make it nonlinear?

Comment: Equation containing $xy$ is nonlinear if both are variables. The fundamental property of linear equations is that linear combination of solutions is also a solution. But if you add $x,y$ pairs solving say $xy-y=0$, like $(1,2)$ and $(4,0)$ you will not get a pair that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of an equation is not only in the formula expressing it, but also by what the equation is being solved for. The functions that are not solved for are considered as *known*, although they are not necessarily given by an explicit formula. Thus:

- If we solve for $y$, treating $x$ as known, this is a linear ODE of third order
- If we solve for $x$, treating $y$ as known, this is a nonlinear ODE of second order
- If we solve for both $x$ and $y$, this is a nonlinear ODE, and we should probably look for a second equation for this pair of functions.

As [Conifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921941/is-this-differential-equation-linear#comment1903303_921941) explained,

> Equation containing $xy$ is nonlinear if both are variables. The fundamental property of linear equations is that linear combination of solutions is also a solution. But if you add $x,y$ pairs solving say $xy-y=0$, like $(1,2)$ and $(4,0)$ you will not get a pair that solves it.